# Hangout problem

Tags: contacts, google-hangouts

My 'A' contact is deleted from my most contacts list on gmail account but still that person is visible on my frequently contacted list in hangout. Please suggest me something because it is very irritating.

Answer (score 1):

Go in **Hangouts** -> **Frequent contacts** -> **press** the contact you want to **delete** for **2s** -> **hide contact**.

Hope it will help.